# How to check that a user-defined function works in r?

Tags: r, function

THis is probably a very silly question, but how can I check if a function written by myself will work or not?

I'm writing a not very simple function involving many other functions and loops and was wondering if there are any ways to check for errors/bugs, or simply just check if the function will work. Do I just create a simple fake data frame and test on it?

As suggested by other users in the comment, I have added the part of the function that I have written. So basically I have a data frame with good and bad data, and bad data are marked with flags. I want to write a function that allows me to produce plots as usual (with the flag points) when user sets flag.option to 1, and remove the flag points from the plot when user sets flag.option to 0.

```
AIR.plot <- function(mydata, flag.option) {
if (flag.option == 1) {
par(mfrow(2,1))
conc <- tapply(mydata$CO2, format(mydata$date, "%Y-%m-%d %T"), mean)
dates <- seq(mydata$date[1], mydata$date[nrow(mydata(mydata))], length =     nrow(conc))
plot(dates, conc,
     type = "p",
     col = "blue",
     xlab = "day",
     ylab = "CO2"), error = function(e) plot.new(type = "n")
barplot(mydata$lines, horiz = TRUE, col = c("red", "blue")) # this is just a   small bar plot on the bottom that specifies which sample-taking line (red or  blue) is providing the samples
} else if (flag.option == 0) {
# I haven't figured out how to write this part yet but essentially I want to  remove all
# of the rows with flags on
}
}
```

Thanks in advance, I'm not an experienced R user yet so please help me.

Comment: What is it intended to do? What does it actually do? Are they the same? Why didn't you just include the function in your question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correctness_(computer_science) 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_analysis

Comment: What do you mean by "work". Do you mean "return without an error"? Or perform the expected behaviour, where you have a formal specification of what said behaviour should be? Or returns the "correct" output for a given set of input, where the correct output is predefined? You're question as it is is too vague and too broad.There is no silly question, don't worry! Just add details and clarify what you mean.

Comment: From what I am inferring, you are writing a function *yourself* and you want to check that it is working as intended. The usual way to do this is to write tests. So yes, by all means, create a dummy data.frame and test the behaviour of your function and check it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: @cory I have added the function in my question

Comment: @antoine-sac I want to check both: a, if the function returns without an error, and b, as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before we (meaning, at my workplace) release any code to our production environment we run through a series of testing procedures to make sure our code behaves the way we want it to.  It usually involves several people with different perspectives on the code.

Ideally, such verification should start before you write any code.  Some questions you should be able to answer are:

1. What should the code do?
2. What inputs should it accept? (including type, ranges, etc)
3. What should the output look like?
4. How will it handle missing values?
5. How will it handle NULL values?
6. How will it handle zero-length values?

If you prepare a list of requirements *and* write your documentation *before* you begin writing any code, the probability of success goes up pretty quickly.  Naturally, as you begin writing your code, you may find that your requirements need to be adjusted, or the function arguments need to be modified.  That's okay, but *document those changes when they happen*.

While you are writing your function, use a package like `assertthat` or `checkmate` to write as many argument checks as you need in your code.  Some of the best, most reliable code where I work consists of about 100 lines of argument checks and 3-4 lines of what the code actually is intended to do.  It may seem like overkill, but you prevent a lot of problems from bad inputs that you never intended for users to provide.

When you've finished writing your function, you should at this point have a list of requirements *and* clearly documented expectations of your arguments.  This is where you make use of the `testthat` package.

- Write tests that verify all of the requirements you wrote are met.
- Write tests that verify you can no put in unintended inputs and get the results you want.
- Write tests that verify you get the output  you intended on your test data.
- Write tests that test any edge cases you can think of.

It can take a long time to write all of these tests, but once it is done, any further development is easier to check since anything that violates your existing requirements should fail the test.

That being said, I'm really bad at following this process in my own work.  I have the tendency to write code, then document what I did.  But the best code I've written has been where I've planned it out conceptually, wrote my documentation, coded, and then tested against my documentation.

Comment: this is a very helpful and thorough instruction. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As @antoine-sac pointed out in the links, some things cannot be checked programmatically; for example, if your function terminates.

Looking at it pragmatically, have a look at the packages [`assertthat`](https://github.com/hadley/assertthat) and [`testthat`](https://github.com/hadley/testthat). `assertthat` will help you insert checks of results "in between", `testthat` is for writing proper tests. Yes, the usual way of writing tests is creating a small test example including test data.